# Lexical and Semantic Errors in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Recently I had to give examples for Lexical and Semantic Errors in C. I have provided the following examples.

I thought the following was lexical error,

```
int a#;
```

And for semantic error I gave the following example,

```
int a[10];
a=100;
```

But now I am a bit confused whether both are in fact syntax errors. Please provide me some idea about these errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535319/what-can-create-a-lexical-error-in-c this is about lexical errors and about semantic errors (and syntax) check out this one http://space.wccnet.edu/~pmillis/cps120/cps120_pgm_syntax.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the classification of errors (as lexical, syntactic, semantic, pragmatic) is somehow arbitrary in the detail.

If you define a lexical error as an error detected by the [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), then a malformed number could be one, eg `12q4z5`. Or a name with a prohibited character like `$`

You could define a syntactic error as one detected at [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29) time. However C is not *stricto sensu* a [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), and its parsers keep contextual information (e.g. in symbol tables).

Since all of `a` `#` and `;` are valid lexemes your `a#;` is not a lexical error.

<sup>Actually `#` is mostly useful at preprocessing time, and what is parsed is actually the preprocessed form, not the user-given source code!</sup>

Many semantic errors are related to the notion of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), like `printf("%d")` which lacks an integer argument. Or out of bound access, in your case `printf("%d\n", a[1234]);`

Some (but not all) semantic or pragmatic errors can be find thru [static analysis tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_analysis_tool). You can even say that modern compilers (when all warnings are enabled) do some.
Your example of `a=100;` is a [typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) error (which could be arbitrarily called as syntactic, since the *C* compiler finds it at parsing time, and as semantic, since related to types which are not a context free property). And you have more specialized static analysis tools like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) and you could *extend* or *customize* the GCC compiler (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), a domain specific language) to add yours (like e.g. in [TALPO](http://gitorious.org/talpo/talpo)).

A pragmatic error could be to declare a huge local variable, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15165635/841108). Probably, when 1Tbyte RAM memory will be common, stacks would have many gigabytes, so that example would run, but not today.

Comment: I just did that in my answer. Can't you find them inside?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you please help me to clarify my doubt. What if I have code in C as `int a2.5b;`. It is not a valid identifier at all but what tokens are generated for this? Is it `int` as reserved keyword, `a` as valid identifier, `2` as valid constant, `.` as special symbol, `5` as valid constant and `;`as special symbol. Is my understanding correct?